¿Cómo se puede seleccionar los datos de una columna asociados a un valor en un dataframe en pandas?
Es la primera vez que escribo por aquí y espero hacerlo bien!
Disculpad mi ignorancia porque a lo mejor estoy preguntando una tontería, pero estoy realizando un máster de big data y Business intelligence y en la parte de programación con python me están surgiendo muchas dudas. En este caso relacionado con un csv de datos covid, me piden que seleccione los valores de la columna "province_state" cuyos "recovered" sean 0.
Se me había ocurrido aplicar una máscara booleana pero no sé si hay alguna otra manera utilizando una expresión por etiquetas o índices parecida a:
print (df[["Province_State", df.Recovered = 0 ]])

No sé si se puede adjuntar un archivo para que se pueda ver el csv así que voy a ver si puedo pegar una captura.

He filtrado los valores = 0 de la columna "recovered" para que se entienda mejor, pero hay de todo tipo de valores.
Un saludo y muchísimas gracias de antemano! :D

Hola Álvaro, bienvenido a [es.so].Una recomendación, agrega siempre que puedas un fragmento del csv (u archivo de turno) como texto (en vez de una captura) a la pregunta,no tiene que ser el archivo completo, basta con algunas lineas representativas del problema con el fin de proporcionar un [mcve]. Lo mismo se aplica al código, siempre como texto, no imágenes.Esto ayudará mucho a quien intente responder y muy posiblemente obtendrás respuestas más rápidas y mejores.En este caso concreto realmente los datos del csv no tienen mucha importancia ya que la pregunta es bastante genérica. Saludos.

Buenas tardes, muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta detallada y completa. Probaré los diferentes métodos para resolverlo. Tomo nota de los comentarios sobre las publicaciones! Discúlpame! :D Un saludo y feliz fin de semana!

Tienes varias formas de seleccionar una columna en base a una condición aplicada sobre otra. Partiendo de un ejemplo simplificado:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Province_State": list("ABCDEFG"),
    "Recovered": [0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 4, 0]
})

Indizado boleano con el operador []
>>> df[df["Recovered"] == 0]["Province_State"]
0    A
3    D
4    E
6    G
Name: Province_State, dtype: object

Filtro boleano junto a loc(filas, columna):
>>> df.loc[df['Recovered'] == 0, 'Province_State']
0    A
3    D
4    E
6    G
Name: Province_State, dtype: object

Usar pandas.DataFrame.query():
>>> df.query("Recovered == 0")["Province_State"]
0    A
3    D
4    E
6    G
Name: Province_State, dtype: object

Más allá de la sintaxis, query() generalmente es más eficente que las otras opciones para DataFrames relativamente grandes y al usar una expresíón en una cadena de texto es útil en algunas situaciones, como generar consultas dinámicamente.

Puedes usar la "notacion punto" (acceso a atributos) si lo prefieres, pero a mi personalmente me gusta evitarla por consistencia y para evitar errores en ciertas situaciones (asignaciones, columnas con nombres que no son identificadores Python válidos o colisionan con nombres de métodos existentes , etc):
df[df.Recovered == 0].Province_State
df.query("Recovered == 0").Province_State
df.loc[df.Recovered == 0, 'Province_State']

Hay más formas de filtrar, algunas de ellas útiles para casos concretos, como pandas.DataFrame.where() / pandas.Series.where() que generá un DataFrame/Serie que preserva las dimenciones del original:
>>> df["Province_State"].where(df["Recovered"] == 0)
0      A
1    NaN
2    NaN
3      D
4      E
5    NaN
6      G
Name: Province_State, dtype: object


Buenas tardes, de acuerdo, así para la próxima ya lo sé. Como era un comentario muy largo por el error, no sabía si hacer varios comentarios o añadir una respuesta. Por otro lado, tienes toda la razón, como estuve probando varias cosas, lo dejé escrito del revés!!! Una vez solucionado, me he fijado que me entrega la columna filtrada de los países, pero existe la opción de que te devuelta una columna con los países filtrados y además otra con la columna "Recovered" con sus valores 0 ? Un saludo y muchas gracias!

¿@AlvaroGarciaLinares te refieres a que en el resultado final aparezcan ambas columnas en vez de solo la de "Province_State"? Si es eso, en el caso de loc sería df.loc[df['Recovered'] == 0, ['Province_State', 'Recovered']] Puedes seleccionar las columnas que quieras de esta misma forma, o todas con: df.loc[df['Recovered'] == 0] que es lo mismo que df.loc[df['Recovered'] == 0, :]

Justo! a eso me refería! siento si pregunto cosas absurdas, ahora mismo tengo un lío con todo... que madre mía jajaaj. Muchísimas gracias por todo! @FJSevilla
